# Combinatorics- monotonic subsequence

Tags: combinatorics

For each natural number $n$, find a sequence of $n^2$ real numbers which contains no monotonic subsequence of more than $n$ terms.

I've been stuck on this for a while. Can somebody please point me in the right direction? Many Thanks.

Comment: Hint: The $n^2$ bound is strict; if the sequence consists of $(n^2+1)$ numbers, it would certainly contain a monotonic subsequence of more than $(n+1)$ terms. Thus, the $n^2$ case is quite likely to contain many increasing sequences of exactly $n$ elements. Can you find such a sequence of $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Answer (score 3):

HINT: $n=4$:

```
                                                                 *  
                                                                   *  
                                                                     *  
                                                                       *  

                                                 *  
                                                   *  
                                                     *  
                                                       *  

                                 *  
                                   *  
                                     *  
                                       *  

                  *  
                    *  
                      *  
                        *
```

Comment: @sciona: Thanks!

Comment: Nice! So we just extend same structure to n^2 terms? And how would you write the general term?

Comment: @Richard: You can do it for any $n$, not just $4$. Write down a permutation of $[n^2]=\{1,\ldots,n^2\}$: for $n=4$ the diagram yields the permutation $$4,3,2,1,8,7,6,5,12,11,10,9,16,15,14,13\;.$$ In general you get $n$ blocks of $n$; the $k$-th block starts with $kn$, so it’s not too hard to describe the $i$-th term of the $k$-th block.